# Topology exercise- Shouldn't $\subset$ be replace by $\subseteq$?

Tags: general-topology

I am transcribing the exercise 3.10 from "Measures, Integrals and Martingales" from  Robert Schilling.

> We can introduce a topology $\mathcal O_A$ on $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$
>   as follows: A subset (proper?) $V \color{red}{\subset}A$ is called open relative to
>   $A$ if $$V=A\cap U$$ for some $U\in\mathcal O^n$ (the family of open
>   sets in $\mathbb R^n$). We  write then $\mathcal O_A$ for the open
>   sets relative to $A$.
>
> **Show that $\mathcal O_A$ is a topology on $A$**

In order to be a topology we must have that $A\in\mathcal O_A$, but $A$ is not "open relative to $A$" according to the definition. Basically because $A\color{red}{\not\subset} A$.

Shouldn we use  $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$? (even though one could say that a set is closed with respect to itself).

How could we deal with this notation issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ are used quite interchangeably, so Schilling very likely meant that $A\subset B$ also if $A=B$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I had the same feeling, but what made me doubt about it was the fact that in the previous line he used $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$

Comment: It might also just be a print error. Such things happen in books.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: I don't think they are used interchangeably. Rather, there are different conventions, one where $\subset$ means subset, and one where $\subset$ means proper subset; a single text usually only uses one of those conventions consistently.

Answer (score 1):

I don't personally make a difference between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$, and I never use $\subseteq$ in personal writing.

This being said, if you insist on making a difference and using the former for proper subsets only, then yes, you should use the latter here, since the total space is always an open set in any topology.